# How to authenticate login in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am having a code for login which is in my AuthController like this.

```
     public function login(Request $request){
     $email = $request->input('email');
     $password = $request->input('password');
     $validation = array(
    'email' =>'required',
    'password' => 'required');
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validation);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        return redirect('login_with_assismo')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        if (auth()->authenticate()) {
        return redirect()->intended('welcome');
    }
}
}
```

When i use this is i think login performs but it redirect me to the page somthng like this
localhost:8000/login

Anyone help me how to authenticate login am i doing something wrong or what. Please get the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`attempt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) function to login the user as:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $rules = array(
        'email' =>'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      $messages = $validator->messages();
      return redirect('login_with_assismo')
                  ->withErrors($validator)
                  ->withInput($request->except('password'));
    }

    if (auth()->attempt($inputs)) {
        return redirect()->intended('welcome');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

Comment: when i am using this code it redirects me to localhost:8000/home
which is page not found.

Comment: And my password is in encrypted form

Comment: You have to not worry about password because Laravel's `attempt()` function will automatically do that for you. Also, I have updated the answer, please use that. And for the problem you are facing you need check manually at which line it's redirecting using `dd()`. I will advise you to read the documentation thoroughly.

Comment: under Namespace i have used 
use Auth;    Is it right.

Comment: If you are using `auth()` helper function then that is not required actually.

Comment: Oh it is working now, there was some cache issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the Auth facade, as described here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

Dont panic bro its because of Auth middleware go with `@amit's` code just go to

> `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`

and replace this route with your's

> `if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
>               return redirect('/home');
>           }`

after that you are good to go